# Stored Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that update my SQL Server table through a webpage.

What I'm trying to do is check sql table to see any existing data, if so update table with new data; else insert new data into the table.

But when I try to execute it returns this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_TagNumberUpdate, Line 46
>   Incorrect syntax near '@return'.

Here's my SQL code:

```
USE [ABCSystem]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TagNumberUpdate] 
@sONbr nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SOLine nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@SerialNbr nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@StatusCode nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PackType nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PalletID nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@PackingListNo nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@ItemCode nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CrDateTime nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@CrUserID nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@return nvarchar(50) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @return = NULL

    IF EXISTS(SELECT sONbr , SOLine
              FROM [BCSystem].[dbo].[TAGNUMBERTEST]
              WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [BCSystem].[dbo].[NEW_SO_TAG_NUMBERTEST]
    SET     SerialNbr = @SerialNbr
            ,StatusCode = @StatusCode
            ,PackType = @PackType
            ,PalletID = @PalletID
            ,PackingListNo = @PackingListNo
            ,ItemCode = @ItemCode
            ,LastUpdDateTime = GETDATE()
            ,LastUpdUserID = @CrUserID

    WHERE sONbr = @sONbr AND SOLine = @SOLine
    @return = 'UPDATE COMPLETE'
END

ELSE
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

            INSERT INTO [ABCSystem].[dbo].[TAGNUMBERTEST]
            (SONbr
            ,SOLine
            ,SerialNbr
            ,StatusCode
            ,PackType
            ,PalletID
            ,PackingListNo
            ,ItemCode
            ,CrDateTime
            ,CrUserID)
            VALUES
            (@sONbr
            ,@SOLine
            ,@SerialNbr
            ,@StatusCode
            ,@PackType
            ,@PalletID
            ,@PackingListNo
            ,@ItemCode
            ,GETDATE()
            ,@CrUserID)

        COMMIT TRAN

        RETURN ERROR_NUMBER()
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
        RETURN ERROR_NUMBER()
    END CATCH
END
END
```

Comment: You are aware of the fact that starting a transaction for just one insert is unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `SET` keyword. It must read:

```
SET @return = 'UPDATE COMPLETE'
```

You can not change a variable without the `SET` keyword.

On a side note, if you're using Microsoft SQL Server, what are the `MySQL` and `SQL` tags doing there? I'm going to remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the point out! I really miss that spot of it. & sorry for the inconvenient about the tagging =.="